# Getting Java style Iterator from QMap<K, T> without specifying T, K

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

Is there any way obtaining java style iterator from QMap without specifying K and T explicitly ?

for example, writing

```
QMap<QString, SomeType> map;
auto qIt = map.getIterator();
```

Instead of

```
QMap<QString, SomeType> map;
QMapIterator<QString, SomeType> qIt(map);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you expect that the iterator represents?

Comment: just for less coding. using auto in C++ is very interesting, in the case of QMapIterator, the usage of auto will be limited and you should explicitly define the types which is used by the qmap and sometime it can be tedious

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but it may help others to know that STL-style iterators work happily with `for (auto iter=map.cbegin (); iter != map.cend (); ++iter) {...}`. I've no idea whether non-const iterators work as well, it's just that I generally use const iterators as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to save on some repetitive typing then you could write a small function template to take advantage of the fact that the template parameters will be deduced from the passed arguments...

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
QMapIterator<Key, Value> make_qiter (QMap<Key, Value> &map)
{
  return(QMapIterator<Key, Value>(map));
}
```

Then use as...

```
QMap<QString, SomeType> map;
auto qIt = make_qiter(map);
```